# Typescript class customize JSON serialization & deserialization

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, bigint

I have a wrapper class in TS that accepts a string in constructor and converts into a bigint internally. I want to customize the serialization/deserialization of this class's object,

```
export class MyInt64 implements MyDataTypes {
    private readonly _internal: BigInt;

    constructor(val: string) {
        this._internal = BigInt(val);
    }
    toJSON() {
        return {
            val: this._internal,
        };
    }
}
```

when  `JSON.stringify(new MyInt64("9223372036854775807"))` gets called I want it to not round the number down to `9223372036854776000`.

How to do this?

---

### Edit

For my type `MyInt64` I want the JSON.stringify() yield into string and that I can do it by overriding toJSON() and keeping track of an internal string variable.

However I want to do `MyJSON.stringify()` which wraps JSON.stringify() and converts the string value of MyInt64 to number.

---

### Clarification

```
export interface IUser {
    id: MyInt64;
    name: string;
    balance: number;
}
```

```
const user : IUser = {
                id: new MyInt64("9223372036854775807"),
                name: "Alice",
                balance: 123
};

// normal framework serialization & deserialization
const userString1 = JSON.stringify(user);
// This is expected to be {"id":"9223372036854775807","name":"Alice","balance":123}


const userStringCustom = JSON.stringify(user, (k, v) => {
    if (value instanceof MyInt64) {
     // call JSONBig.stringify(value) using json-bingint lib
    }
});
// This is expected to be {"id":9223372036854775807,"name":"Alice","balance":123}
```

Comment: Well, technically right now it's not rounding down. It's just throwing an error, since BigInt cannot be converted to JSON

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be:

```
  toJSON() {
    return { val: this._internal.toString() };
  }
```

You may want to include some sort of type identifier, so that upon deserialization you can tell these objects apart from anything else that's serialized as `{val: "some_string_which_may_be_numeric"}`.

If your BigInts are large (let's say, hundreds or thousands of bits), you can improve performance by using hex strings (because conversions between internal binary number representations and hex strings are easy and fast, whereas conversions between binary numbers and decimal strings are expensive computational work). Based on your class name "MyInt64" I'm guessing that the difference won't be measurable for your case; I'm mentioning the idea here for completeness and future readers.

Put together, that'd give something like:

```
  toJSON() {
    return {
      type: "MyInt64",
      val: "0x" + this._internal.toString(16),
    };
  }
```

For deserialization, you can use a [reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), something like:

```
JSON.parse(..., (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === "object" && value.type === "MyInt64") {
    return new MyInt64(value.val);
  }
  // Optionally handle other special cases here...
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you jmrk. Is it possible to customize JSON.stringify() other than by modifying the toJSON() method? I edited the question

Comment: @user3833308 I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to drop the quotes, i.e. get `val: 123` instead of `val: "123"`? I suppose you could do that with regexp-powered replacement, but I think that would make it impossible to recover the precise value when deserializing, because it would get rounded to Number precision before reaching the reviver function. Unless, of course, you perform another regexp replacement before calling `JSON.parse(...)`. But then I don't see the point of adding so much extra work and brittleness.

Comment: first of all +1. My usecase is: I have a user struct that contains one of the proeprty of type my wrapper class. This user struct is serialized and deserialized in multiple places in application (such as: rest framework, log framework and my library). I want it to serialize with "9223372036854775807" at all places. Only in my lib I want this to be serialized like `9223372036854775807` - I can do this by using third party library such as json-bigint. but how do I just customize it for my library usage. if I override toJSON() it reflects everywhere.

Comment: Added clarification section in question.

Comment: As I said, you can use a regexp-replacement, e.g. `JSON.stringify(...).replaceAll(/"id":"(\d+)"/g, '"id":$1')`. But be warned that this will make deserialization difficult. In other words: I suspect that this isn't a good idea. Serializing BigInts as strings is safer.