# javascript parsing backend data of long type loses precision

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

The data structure parses the data of the Object type in C#. No matter how the front end uses js to parse this data, the precision will be lost.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>BigNumber.js示例</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bignumber.js/bignumber.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const jsonStr = '{"total": 8, "items": [{ "userId": "601d1b35-0221-427b-b3f9-b0f8a884a043", "startWay": 0, "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "adc5ef31-a122-4868-a0a8-226712546a86", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:07+08:00", "eventName": "TaskStarted" }, { "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "5043873d-bdd3-43f8-881b-958cb4759e74", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:08+08:00", "eventName": "TaskSplitStarted" }, { "subTasks": [{ "subTaskId": "0d54fb77-3705-43ab-85cf-07804af8ebc5", "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "dispatchNo": "4baf8ff6-58e3-4d56-9ddd-8f4e3057c98a", "sequence": 1, "cloudId": "cb656221-d900-43b2-adfd-78610f72e4bb", "clusterId": "b05fdf6a-f6c8-4a72-9083-eb3cf7494f90", "clusterGroup": 95, "status": 4, "resendCount": 0, "createdTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:08+08:00", "sentTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:11+08:00", "startTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:13+08:00", "endTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:48+08:00", "executeSeconds": 35, "isEnded": true }] }, { "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "ad407d3c-4a89-4ecb-a6b9-9b3cdf5bfee9", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:08+08:00", "eventName": "SubTasksCreated" }, { "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "260ba91f-091d-4b7b-945d-f1d1ea0c411e", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:08+08:00", "eventName": "TaskSplitFinished" }, { "subTaskId": "0d54fb77-3705-43ab-85cf-07804af8ebc5", "clusterGroup": 95, "sequence": 1, "dispatchNo": "4baf8ff6-58e3-4d56-9ddd-8f4e3057c98a", "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "0d21fcfb-a8c1-478f-ab64-55ba8899c53c", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:11+08:00", "eventName": "SubTaskSent" }, { "subTaskId": "0d54fb77-3705-43ab-85cf-07804af8ebc5", "sequence": 1, "cloudId": "cb656221-d900-43b2-adfd-78610f72e4bb", "clusterId": "b05fdf6a-f6c8-4a72-9083-eb3cf7494f90", "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "78f7e094-ad76-4b51-93b6-dfbbe496b9e5", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:13+08:00", "eventName": "SubTaskExecuted" }, { "subTaskId": "0d54fb77-3705-43ab-85cf-07804af8ebc5", "sequence": 1, "cloudId": "cb656221-d900-43b2-adfd-78610f72e4bb", "clusterId": "b05fdf6a-f6c8-4a72-9083-eb3cf7494f90", "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "f15cf411-4882-4cb1-80a7-11df3f0fed38", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:48+08:00", "eventName": "SubTaskFinished" }, { "taskId": "6b41c1eb-32a4-45a5-9937-47d4bd24471c", "lotNo": 638258760079874090, "id": "c3c7312a-4315-4dd9-801e-8a156f85514c", "creationTime": "2023-07-25T10:00:48+08:00", "eventName": "TaskFinished" }]}';
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr, (key, value) => {
      if (key === 'lotNo') {
        return new BigNumber(value);
      }
      return value;
    });
    console.log(jsonObj.items[0].lotNo.toString()); // 输出：638258760079874090
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: orginnal-data]

Comment: it should be 638258760079874090 rather than  638258760079874000

Comment: Your number is much larger than what can be represented in any common double-precision floating point system. You can try `bigint` or strings to represent your values. (The `bigint` type cannot be used in JSON.)

Comment: I count 18 digits. That should fit into a .NET `Int64` (aka C#'s `long`). Just fit

Comment: Looking at your code again, you're doing the deserialization in JavaScript; you'll need to look up how the JavaScript JSON object handles large `number`s

Comment: @Flydog57 yea and JavaScript does not have 64 bit long values

Comment: Oh yeah, Javascript underlying type for `number` is floating point. You're not going to get 18 digits of precision from an IEEE floating point number. What do you mean by _"The data structure parses the data of the Object type in C#"_? If you can move the deserialization into C# and Deserialize into a `long` it should work

Comment: Consider also this question - use a Javascript "reviver" function?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808039/typescript-class-customize-json-serialization-deserialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the number to a string in c# before sending the lot number over to the java script side. In some cases it is easier to handle identifiers as strings, as long as you do not need to store them in a database, or do arithmetic on them.

As mentioned in the comments, Javascript does not have the concept of a 64 bit integer, it handles all numbers as 64 bit floating point values, but such values only have a 53 bit effective significant, not enough to express your value precisely.

An alternative solution would be to use [BigInt](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bigint.asp) that can express arbitrary large integers.

Comment: Yes, you're all right.  My current approach is to put the parsing work on the backend of C#, and then redundantly save a string for the frontend to recognize with javascript.